# ML-insert new data to machine learning model

Tags: model

i'm new to Ml , i want to enter new data to **trained** model to make prediction ,new data is in the **SAMPLE.csv**,but i get this error

```
 modelfile = 'voting.pkl'
 model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))
 iris = pd.read_csv("Sample3.csv")
    x = np.array(iris)
    response = np.array2string(model.predict(x))
    return jsonify(response)
```

error :
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'